# pulling image to pod from docker hub registry throwing error Context Exceed Timeout

Tags: docker, image, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, docker-registry

I am facing error while pulling image into pod by docker hub registry. first it goes to images pulling for 200s then after through error that

Comment: can you please provide logs from the ```kubelet```, we can then proceed to finding out the error. Kubelet is the process that pulls the images

Comment: could you describe the pod & share the log: `$ kubectl describe pods -n <namespace> <pod-name>`

Comment: Okay let me check. however i share with you

Comment: Type     Reason   Age                    From     Message
  ----     ------   ----                   ----     -------
  Normal   Pulling  54m (x7 over 79m)      kubelet  Pulling image "xxxx7:latest"
  Normal   BackOff  9m51s (x182 over 77m)  kubelet  Back-off pulling image "xxxxx7:latest"
  Warning  Failed   2m57s (x14 over 77m)   kubelet  Failed to pull image "xxxx7:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = context deadline exceeded

Comment: Could you help me finding kubelet log

Comment: What's the size of the `image` you're trying to pull?

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou everyone for the help basically I was running on minikube on ubuntu and ubuntu is my virtual machine I did not sync environment of minikube with docker when  kubelet look for image it check within minikube images and images was not availble when I synced pod started running

Comment: This is not an answer, you should post it as a comment